# how to change mysql table auto_increment primary key

Tags: mysql

Now i have a table with Auto_increment id as Pri key, and exchange_id as key, How could I change the primary key to field [ticker]..?

[image: table]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `auto_increment` field must be an index, or be the first column of one. If you try to just drop the primary key, MySQL will complain. You have to delete the `auto_increment` property before moving it:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY id int, DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (ticker);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> desc mytable;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| exchange_id       | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| ticker            | varchar(32)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| instrument        | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sector            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| currency          | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| created_date      | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_updated_date | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want `id` to continue being `auto_increment`, you have to do also:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX `id` (id), MODIFY id int auto_increment;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> desc mytable;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    | auto_increment |
| exchange_id       | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ticker            | varchar(32)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| instrument        | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sector            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| currency          | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_date      | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_updated_date | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please make sure to create if with the right index (multiple, unique) and nullability (null, not null).

Please also note that, *depending on the engine used and/or the queries to be performed*, a character field for a primary key may be suboptimal.

Comment: Love u ..How do u format the tables(grey background part) in your answers?

Comment: It is four spaces+ in front of the text. It is done automatically with the 5th button on the toolbar: http://cdn.sstatic.net/dba/Img/wmd-buttons.png

Comment: @Xun Bao Feel free to close the answer if this was helpful!